# Content is not shown until I expand elements in developer console

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I have an interesting issue with Edge running a Angular (v5.2.1) web application. On a start page I have some content which disappears when I navigate to some other page and back to the start page. When I inspect the DOM in Elements tab in developer console, I can see that the elements for the missing content exist. As soon as I expand them, the relevant content appears on the page. The content appears even if I maximize or restore the window.

What could be the possible cause of this behavior?
Here is the demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsAsy4-s-7o.

The most relevant code for the component which is not working properly is following:

`<ng-container *ngIf="isAuth && account.access.graphs">
     <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
</ng-container>`

As far as I can see, the `isAuth` and `account.access.graphs` are set to true but the component is still no visible until I do manipulations.

The application works fine in all other browsers including IE11.

Comment: @Tha'erM.Al-Ajlouni, sorry, please try again.

Comment: You need to show us the code that you used to build that part, or else we can't help you.

Comment: There is much code but I updated the post with the most relevant.

Comment: Does the problem appear if you don't open developer console? I'd suggest to improve the question by providing working demo and steps to replicate the problem there.

Comment: @estus, yes, the problem appear if I run with no developer console. I will try to reproduce this problem with less code.

Comment: @Azimuth there are errors in your console, take a look at them, maybe there is a Edge specific error causing the angular app to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a third flag and starting a timer in `ngOnInit` which would set this flag to `true` after couple of seconds.